# Calculator in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following assignment:

Write a complete 8086 program to perform the calculator functions: ADD/SUB/DIV/MUL.
When the user presses "=" your program should display the result. Only the numbers from 0-9 are input.

```
    ones  db ?
    tens  db ?

    mov   ah,1
    int   21h
    add   al,30H
    mov   tens, al
    mov   ah,1       
    int   21H 
    mov   dl,al
    cmp   dl, '+'
    je    addition

addition:
    mov   ah,1    
    int   21h
    mov   bl,al   
    mov   ones,al
```

I have to do it by adding `30h` to each number then subtracting it. Can someone explain how I can do this?

Comment: Homework should be tagged as homework :)

Comment: _I have to do it by adding 30h to each number then subtracting it can someone explain it to me?_ ← something tells me you didn't write that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x30 is the 0 sign in ASCII so if you want to print a number between 0-9 you should add 0x30 to the value to make it an '0' character. If you read from the terminal you would read 0x30 instead of 0 so if you want to make calculation with it you would need to subtract 0x30 to convert an '0' character to the value 0

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @lana, if this answers your question, you should click on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it in C or some other language (dont use any C libraries for the bulk of the code just simple language).

I assume you are taking in ASCII values and spitting out ASCII values?

Look at an ASCII chart, the ASCII for 0 is 0x30 which is also decimal 48 or binary 0b00110000
1 is 0x31, 2 is 0x32, and so on, in binary:

```
0 0b00110000
1 0b00110001
2 0b00110010
3 0b00110011
4 0b00110100
5 0b00110101
6 0b00110110
7 0b00110111
8 0b00111000
9 0b00111001
```

If you wanted to add the numbers 9 and 8 you probably want 0x09 and 0x08 in your registers not 0x39 and 0x38.  0x09+0x08 = 0x11  0x39 + 0x38 = 0x71

```
0x11 0b00010001
0x71 0b01110001
```

It might be difficult to reliably extract the proper bits from the result if you dont convert from ascii before doing anything.  not bad with addition, you could hack your way through that but get into multiplication, etc it might be less pretty.  You have to figure this out on your own.

Then you need to get from the binary result back to ascii, I assume you want to print the result in ascii?

How do you get from 0x11 which is 17 decimal to ascii 0x31, 0x37?  If someone asks you how many feet are in 78 inches, what is the answer?  you start by dividing feet by 12, right, you get 6 with a remainder of 6, which translates to 6 feet 6 inches.  How many hours, minutes, seconds are in 4000 seconds?  4000/3600 = 1 remainder 400, 400 / 60 = 6 remainder 40, 1:06:40.  And if I were to ask if I have the number 123 how do I extract the hundreds, tens and ones mathematically (so that I can add 0x30 to each and print them out as ASCII).

So adding 9 and 8 you will  likely get 0b00111001 and 0b00111000 and a plus sign and an equals sign as inputs, you need to turn 0x00111001 into 0x00001001 and 0x00111000 into 0x00001000 before doing the addition then turn the result 0x00010001 into 0x00000001 (tens) and 0x00000111 (ones) and then do something to change 0x00000001 into 0x00110001 (tens)(ascii) and 0x00000111 into 0x00110111 (ones)(ascii) before printing out.